# what's the default retry behavior if we don't set any retry template in my consumer configuration?

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using spring boot 2.1.7.RELEASE and spring-kafka 2.2.8.RELEASE.And I'm using @KafkaListener annotation to create a consumer and I'm using all default settings for the consumer.

Now my question is,

1. If I don't set any retry template, Would the consumer have any default retry behavior or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no retry by default; the default error handler will just log the error.

There are two ways to enable retry - in-memory via the `RetryTemplate` or configure a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`.

Comment: Gary Russel could you may be elaborate more on this? It would be very helpful.

Comment: This answer is 2.5 years old. The framework has evolved since then. The default error handler was changed to a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` long ago; that error handler is now deprecated in favor of the new `DefaultErrorHandler`. `RetryTemplate` at the listener adapter is deprecated now that error handlers support back off and exception classification (removed in the upcoming 3.0 release). See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handlers If you still need help, ask another question with more details.

Comment: thank you, I figured this out by setting the below properties in my application.yaml. 
`consumer:
            max-attempts: 10
            back-off-max-interval: 6000
            back-off-initial-interval: 100
            backOffMultiplier: 2`